# Fiber of the Hitchin fibration

Tags: differential-geometry, vector-bundles, fiber-bundles, tangent-bundle

In the paper "More On Gauge Theory And Geometric Langlands" by Edward Witten ( https://arxiv.org/abs/1506.04293 ), he writes about the Hitchin fibration

$\pi: \mathcal{M}_H \rightarrow \mathcal{V}, (E, \varphi) \mapsto Trace(\varphi^2)$

als the "fiber $\mathcal{F}$ of the hitchin fibration".

Now I would intepret "fiber" as $\pi^{-1}(p) \subset \mathcal{M}_H$ for some $ p \in \mathcal{V}$.

But on page 10 he states that "choosing a fiber means making a particular choice of $trace(\varphi^2)$. That's what I don't understand, since $\pi$ doesn't have to be injective and therefore there could be many choices of $\varphi$.

I understand that this question is hard to answer if you don't know the paper and it is asked a lot to read this paper just to answer my question but it would already help a lot if someone could tell me another interoretation of fiber here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most likely, Witten means "choosing a fiber means making a particular choice of $t\in {\mathcal V}$. The fiber then will be $\pi^{-1}(t)=\{\phi: tr(\phi^2)=t\}$."

Comment: Ok, now that I am rereading it, I see that it was just my wrong interpretation, as you said he said "choosing $Trace(\varphi^2)$" which doesn't mean a particular choice of $\varphi$, obviously. Thanks!